# Mocking a method inside my test class

Tags: mockito

```
Android Studio 2.3
```

I have the following method I want to test inside my model class:

```
public class RecipeListModelImp  implements RecipeListModelContract {

    private Subscription subscription;
    private RecipesAPI recipesAPI;
    private RecipeSchedulers recipeSchedulers;

@Inject
public RecipeListModelImp(@NonNull RecipesAPI recipesAPI, @NonNull RecipeSchedulers recipeSchedulers) {
    this.recipesAPI = Preconditions.checkNotNull(recipesAPI);
    this.recipeSchedulers = Preconditions.checkNotNull(recipeSchedulers);
}

@Override
public void getRecipesFromAPI(final RecipeGetAllListener recipeGetAllListener) {
    subscription = recipesAPI.getAllRecipes()
            .subscribeOn(recipeSchedulers.getBackgroundScheduler())
            .observeOn(recipeSchedulers.getUIScheduler())
            .subscribe(new Subscriber<List<Recipe>>() {
                @Override
                public void onCompleted() {
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(Throwable e) {
                   recipeGetAllListener.onRecipeGetAllFailure(e.getMessage());
                }

                @Override
                public void onNext(List<Recipe> recipe) {
                    recipeGetAllListener.onRecipeGetAllSuccess(recipe);
                }
            });
}

@Override
public void shutdown() {
    if(subscription != null && !subscription.isUnsubscribed()) {
        subscription.unsubscribe();
    }
}
}
```

Inside my test class I am testing like this:

```
  public class RecipeListModelImpTest {

    @Mock Subscription subscription;
    @Mock RecipesAPI recipesAPI;
    @Mock RecipeListModelContract.RecipeGetAllListener recipeGetAllListener;
    @Mock List<Recipe> recipes;

    @Inject RecipeSchedulers recipeSchedulers;

    private RecipeListModelContract recipeListModel;

    @Before
    public void setup() {

        TestBusbyComponent testBusbyComponent = DaggerTestBusbyComponent.builder()
                .mockRecipeSchedulersModule(new MockRecipeSchedulersModule())
                .build();

        testBusbyComponent.inject(RecipeListModelImpTest.this);

        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(RecipeListModelImpTest.this);
        recipeListModel = new RecipeListModelImp(recipesAPI, recipeSchedulers);
    }

    @Test(expected = NullPointerException.class)
    public void testShouldThrowExceptionOnNullParameter() {
        recipeListModel = new RecipeListModelImp(null, null);
    }

    @Test
    public void testRecipeListModelShouldNotBeNull() {
        assertNotNull(recipeListModel);
    }

    @Test
    public void testShouldGetRecipesFromAPI() {
        when(recipesAPI.getAllRecipes()).thenReturn(Observable.just(recipes));

        recipeListModel.getRecipesFromAPI(recipeGetAllListener);

        verify(recipesAPI, times(1)).getAllRecipes();
        verify(recipeGetAllListener, times(1)).onRecipeGetAllSuccess(recipes);
        verify(recipeGetAllListener, never()).onRecipeGetAllFailure(anyString());
    }

    @Test
    public void testShouldFailToGetRecipesFromAPI() {
        when(recipesAPI.getAllRecipes())
                .thenReturn(Observable.<List<Recipe>>error(
                        new Throwable(new RuntimeException("Failed to get recipes"))));

        recipeListModel.getRecipesFromAPI(recipeGetAllListener);

        verify(recipesAPI, times(1)).getAllRecipes();
        verify(recipeGetAllListener, times(1)).onRecipeGetAllFailure(anyString());
        verify(recipeGetAllListener, never()).onRecipeGetAllSuccess(recipes);
    }

    @Test
    public void testShouldShutdown() {
        when(subscription.isUnsubscribed()).thenReturn(false);
        final Field subscriptionField;

        try {
            subscriptionField = recipeListModel.getClass().getDeclaredField("subscription");
            subscriptionField.setAccessible(true);
            subscriptionField.set(recipeListModel, subscription);
        } catch(NoSuchFieldException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch(IllegalAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        recipeListModel.shutdown();

        verify(subscription, times(1)).unsubscribe();
    }
}
```

However, the problem is the Subscription in my model class is always null so will never enter the if blook. Is there any way to test this with using Mockito or spys?

Many thanks for any suggestions,

Comment: Sure. Do what you did, but make sure to inject the mock subscription into the RecipeListModel. Without knowing anything about its code, it's hard to give prcise advices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should for testing recipeListModel class, where you have shutdown() method , set mock into this class.

If you don't have set method for subscription in recipeListModel , or constructor param.... ),you can set mock object with reflection  like :

```
@Test
public void testShouldShutdown() {
    Subscription subscription = mock(Subscription.class);
    when(subscription.isUnsubscribed()).thenReturn(false);

    Field subscriptionField = recipeListModel.getClass().getDeclaredField("subscription");
    subscriptionField.setAccessible(true);
    subscriptionField.set(recipeListModel, subscriptionMock);

    recipeListModel.shutdown();

    verify(subscription, times(1)).unsubscribe();
}
```

---

after your update :

if you can't change way of creation , you should mock it like (full way of creation)  , i don't know your api , so it's just idea:

```
Subscription subscription = mock(Subscription.class);
when(subscription.isUnsubscribed()).thenReturn(false);

 // preparation mock for create Subscription
 //for recipesAPI.getAllRecipes()
 Object mockFor_getAllRecipes = mock(....);
 when(recipesAPI.getAllRecipes()).thenReturn(mockFor_getAllRecipes );

//for subscribeOn(recipeSchedulers.getBackgroundScheduler())
 Object mockFor_subscribeOn = mock();
 when(mockFor_getAllRecipes.subscribeOn(any())).thenReturn(mockFor_subscribeOn);

//for .observeOn(recipeSchedulers.getUIScheduler())
 Object mockFor_observeOn = mock();
 when(mockFor_subscribeOn .observeOn(any())).thenReturn(observeOn);


// for .subscribe
when(observeOn.subscribe(any()).thenReturn(subscription);
```

Comment: +sbavateam thanks for the answer. I have edit my questions with my complete source code. I like the idea of setting the method. But it makes the code look very ugly with the exception handling. Is there other way of doing this. Looking at my complete classes? thanks,

Comment: Thanks for the update. However, mocking the API has already been done. As I inject mocks for getAllRecipes. However, I was just enquiring about the verifying the subscription.unsubscribe(). Just wondering if there was anyway of doing it. That is why I posted all my code so you could see the bigger picture. I was just wondering about alternative solution instead of getDeclaredField("...") method.